# Can JSON Array be sent through Url in android

Tags: android, json, url, arraylist, android-json

Url Maximum length:

Although the specification of the HTTP protocol does not specify any maximum length, practical limits are imposed by web browser and server software. Microsoft states that the maximum length of a URL in Internet Explorer is 2,083 characters, with no more than 2,048 characters in the path portion of the URL.

JSON Maximum length:

The maximum length of JSON strings. The default is 2097152 characters, which is equivalent to 4 MB of Unicode string data

I want to send entire Contact list in the form of json array from android application.Here the Size of contact list is much larger than the url size.

Can I send JSON Array of larger size through url?

Comment: Sent via HTTP POST instead of URL param

Comment: You can send using POST which has a maximum size about 2GB

Comment: Thank you sir, Can you please post The sample code of HTTP POST?@BrianHoang

Comment: Thank you sir, Can you please post The sample code of HTTP POST?@ManojPerumarath